# Splitting probability measures into diffuse and non-diffuse parts

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

There is a question I am trying to answer from *Measures, Integrals, and Martingales* by René L. Schilling:

> 6.8(iv): Show that every probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ can be decomposed into a sum of two measures $\mu + \nu$, where $\mu$ is diffuse and $\nu$ is a measure of the form $\nu = \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \epsilon_i \delta_{x_i}, \epsilon_i > 0, x_i \in \mathbb{R}$.

A hint is given:

> Hint: since $\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{R}) = 1$, there are at most $k$ points $y_i^{(k)}$ such that $\frac{1}{k-1} > \mathbb{P}\{y_i^{(k)}\} \geq \frac{1}{k}$. [...]

This first part of the hint makes perfect sense to me, but then the next part I don't fully understand:

> [...] Find by recursion (in $k$) all points satisfying such a relation. There are at most countably many of these $y_i^{(k)}$. There are at most countably many of these $y_i^{(k)}$. Relabel them as $x_1, x_2, \dots$. These are the atoms of $\mathbb{P}$.

(I'm not sure if *atom* is common nomenclature; it refers to a singleton with non-zero measure.)

What confuses me is how I am supposed to recurse in $k$, and why it is necessary.

If we want to show that only countably many atoms exist, is it not enough that for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$, we have that only countably many such $y_i^{(k)}$ exist? Doesn't it directly follow that the total number of atoms must be countable?

Any help in understanding the above is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a [pdf of what looks like the official solutions](http://www.motapa.de/measures_integrals_and_martingales/solutions-mims-2e.pdf) to all the problems from the book.

Interestingly, the "official" answer does not seem to include recursion; it rather just takes the union over k of the sets of atoms in $[\frac{1}{k}, \frac{1}{k-1})$, which is a countable union of finite sets, and is thus countable. As to why the book references recursion I am still unsure.

Comment: I don't think that this is an answer to your question.

Comment: If you are still unsure, then I think it is too soon to post an answer. You can include this information in your question above, or alternatively as a comment attached to your question.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos My question was about why the recursion is necessary. From the official answer I understand that it is not; that answer doesn't use recursion, which leads me to believe that perhaps the hint meant induction instead of recursion, but of course there's no way to know that.